# prove $ b^6c^8-b^5c^7+b^8c^6-b^3c^6+b^2c^6-b^7c^5-b^6c^3+b^6c^2-bc^2+c^2-b^2c+b^2 \ge 0$

Tags: inequality

$b>0,c>0, $  prove $g(b,c)=b^6c^8-b^5c^7+b^8c^6-b^3c^6+b^2c^6-b^7c^5-b^6c^3+b^6c^2-bc^2+c^2-b^2c+b^2 \ge 0$

this is from a middle process of a inequality. (I am sure it is correct because the inequality is proved.)

edit: the inequality is : $abc=1,\dfrac{a}{b^2+c^2+a}+\dfrac{b}{c^2+a^2+b}+\dfrac{c}{a^2+b^2+c} \le 1$ , replace $a=\dfrac{1}{bc}$ ,one can get the  asked inequality.

I try different approach such as $c=b+u,$  or $ c=tb \to b^{12}t^8-b^{10}t^7+b^{12}t^6-b^7t^6+b^6t^6-b^{10}t^5-b^7t^3+b^6t^2-bt^2+t^2-bt+1 \ge 0$

it doesn't work.there is no factor such as $(t-1),(b-1),(bt-1),(b^2t-1),(b-c)$

when $c=b$ we have $(b-1)^2f(b)$ and $ f(b) >0$  so it is clear that $g(b,c)=0 \iff b=c=1$, but how to prove it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: $(b^2 + c^2)$ factors out.

Comment: Could you provide the original inequality, because it probably has more structure that this one.

Comment: $\frac{a}{b^2+c^2+a}+\frac{b}{c^2+a^2+b}+\frac{c}{a^2+b^2+c} \le 1 $

Comment: $abc=1$, sorry for forgeting add.

Comment: @chenbai  You should put the original inequality, as written in your comment, into the posted question, in my opinion. You should also  definitely add the restriction $abc=1$ since otherwise at $a=b=c=t$ the left side is $3/(2t+1)$ which gets as large as $3$ when $t \to 0.$

Comment: @coffeemath thanks for advice. edit it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the following.

AM-GM inequality implies the following inequalities:

$$\frac 12 b^8c^6+\frac 16 b^6c^8+\frac 13 b^6c^2\ge b^7c^5,$$

$$\frac 12 b^6c^8+\frac 16 b^8c^6+\frac 13 b^2c^6\ge b^5c^7,$$

$$\frac 13 b^8c^6+\frac 12 b^6c^2+\frac 16 b^2\ge b^6c^3,$$

$$\frac 13 b^6c^8+\frac 12 b^2c^6+\frac 16 c^2\ge b^3c^6,$$

$$\frac 16 b^6c^2+\frac 56 c^2\ge bc^2,$$

$$\frac 16 b^2c^6+\frac 56 b^2\ge b^2c.$$

When we add all of them, we obtain $g(b,c)\ge 0$.

Comment: nice!,I only think two items.